# how to send multiple data in chartjs label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I recently started using the Chartjs library specifically with the radar chart and I have a problem.

One of the configuration options are the labels, that are the attribute that is being measured, my question is, is there any way to pass all the data found in an array whose size I cannot define since it will change?

what I am doing is processing data that comes to me through surveys made in Excel and this data is stored in several arrangements, one of them corresponds to the name of the questions and I want to pass all these questions to my data from labels but I have not been able to come up with a way to pass all this data to it since if I send an array as such, what it does is that all the data inside the array reads them as 1 single data.

I need for example to send the name of all the questions which are in an array, or if you know any other way it would be of great help to me.

This is something that I have tried but as I said before I have not been successful since it reads everything within an array as a single piece of data.

```
var DATA_COUNT = 6;
            var labels = [];
            

            for (var i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; ++i) {
              labels.push('' + i);
            }

                                // [enter image description here][1]graph configuration
                    var config = {
                        type: 'radar',
                        data: {
                            
                            labels: [labels  <---- this is the problem, i need many differents labels
                                

                            ],
                            datasets: [{

                                label: 'Dato',
                                borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)",
                                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255,255, 0)".......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason this is happening is because chart.js sees arrays in the labels array as multiline labels, to solve your issue change `labels: [labels]` to `labels: labels`